# Odd bitmap factory behavior (android)

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

```
static Boolean[][] squares = new Boolean[32][32];
static BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();

public static Boolean[][] getFrame(int id){

opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;
opts.outHeight = 32;
opts.outWidth = 32;

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.raw.f11, opts);

for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++) {
        int pixel = bmp.getPixel(x, y);

        if(pixel == -1)
            squares[x][y] = false;
        else
            squares[x][y] = true;

        }
}
return squares;
}
```

I'm having an issue here, bitmap factory seems to not be importing my bitmaps correctly. Here's what [the original](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60865697/f11.bmp) looks like and here's [what getPixel](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60865697/Screenshot_2012-03-31-19-32-20.png) (and getPixels) returns me. This happens with and without any options declared. I'd like to know why it seems to be importing 2rds of the picture at 2x resolution. I have tried 1 bit and 4 bit bitmaps as well as declaring the 1 bit and 4 bit Bitmap.Config. Using the Boolean array data to draw rectangles in a grid on a canvas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you noticed it on screen?
If so, what is the xml for the ImageView? Maybe you inadvertently set an erroneous width or height?

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned this part, doing a sort of custom virtual screen, it displays a 32 x 32 grid of rectangles on a canvas, using the Boolean array for it's data, true being an empty square. This makes it independent of screen size. and an issue of getPixel giving me these weird values.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a late answer but I would try

```
opts.inScaled = false;
```